# How to implement try catch with multiple condition in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The below spark code is to create datapipeline.

```
package Test

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


object myjson {def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {



  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Readfile")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
    .master("local[*]")
    //.enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("D:mypathTest/myfile.json")
  df.printSchema()
  val newdf = ds.withColumn("upTime",regexp_replace(col("upTime"),"[a-zA-Z]","")).
   
}
}
```

Is there any way to create Logging and alerting mechanism in spark written Scala.
or
how can i implement error handling like if file not in path error.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For error handling you can use `try/catch` statements. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-try-catch-finally-syntax-examples-exceptions-wildcard/

For logging, you can use log4j. `https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/scala-api.html`

Answer (score 1):

Spark throw InvalidInputException when you pass invalid source in spark read API...

you can have scala code something like below

```
try{
  // reading through spark
}catch{
  case filenotfound :  InvalidInputException => {log.error("please check input ",filenotfound)
    handleException()  
  }
  case others : Exception => handleException()  
}

def handleException()  = {
   // have a notification system like AWS SES or some other alerting systems here
}
```

for logging, you can use log4j framework and create log object and uses it log error.